# How can I show static page during a deployment to Sitecore Manage Cloud?

Tags: azure, paas, deployment, azure-devops, sitecore-managed-cloud

We are using Sitecore Managed Cloud and we have just one CD web app. Obviously when we deploy the website goes down and we would like to show a static page to the users during this time.

Is there an easy way to do this without using deployment slots (which increase the infrastructure cost and the client is not willing to pay for)? How can I configure that?

Comment: We did it using an additional deployment slot. Before deployment itself, traffic was switched to the maintenance slot. After deployment and warm-up, it was switched back to CD slot. 

If you have many CDs, then probably you will be able to cut some cost with redirection of traffic to the one place, instead of slots for each CD. But if you have 1 or 2 CDs, I don't think that you will get any costs to shrink with this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a file called `app_offline.htm` into the root of your app service it will effectively take your app service offline and show the contents of that `htm` file while you are deploying.

If you are using Azure DevOps release pipelines, there is an option to `Take App Offline` in the `Deploy Azure App Service` task. This will place the generic default `app_offline.htm` file for your users to see.

[image]

If you want a custom `app_offline.htm` file, then you will need to use something like kudu to copy your custom file to your webroot before deploying and then removing it post deploy.